Capacity of Queue in transactional send journey
I have a transactional send journey. There is a business use case to pause this journey for couple of days. By pausing the journey i understand that messages will be queued. I want to understand what is maximum capacity of messages a queue can withstand. Will this impact performance of other journeys.

There is no limit, but any subscriber queued over 72hrs will go to error and not be sent, anyone in the queue longer than 14 days will simply be truncated and not error

Does this apply to all journey types or just transactional journey?

this applies to all triggeredsend queues
